# How do I return JSON data from CodeIgniter to Google Apps Script?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-apps-script, chatbot

so we've been making a chatbot in Google Apps Script and one of its functions is to display information from a database (hosted online). The script sends a POST request to a controller function in our CodeIgniter program:

```
function do_post(name, status, duration) {
// Make a POST request with a JSON payload.
var data = {
    'name': name,
    'status': status,
    'key' : api_key,
    'duration' : duration
};
var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
    // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.domainname.com/bot/index.php/bot/process/', options);
Logger.log(response);
return response;
}
```

The function above successfully inserts a record into the database using our process() controller in CI, but the problem is in our response variable. It's of HttpResponse type and we don't know how to return that type from our controller. We want our controller to return something like {"Response": "success"} to our chatbot but we don't know how. We've tried returning a JSON-encoded array:

```
public function process()
{
    $_POST = array_replace($_POST, json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true) ?? []);
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $status = $_POST["status"];
    $api = $_POST["key"];
    $duration = $_POST["duration"];
    if ($api == api_key){
        $result = $this->bot_model->add_log();
    }
    $res_array =  array("response" => $result);
    // encode array to json
    $json = json_encode($res_array);
    return ($json);
    }
}
```

And we try accessing var response in our app script using response.getContentText(), but we get something like "string(39)" and then the value of our api_key. How do we access the json data from  the response?

Comment: Are you sure `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` are making the call synchronously? JS `fetch()` api is asynchronous (returning a promise, not the response since request is most likely not finished at that point). Your PHP is a bit odd. You extract a bunch of data from the response into variables, but you never actually do anything with those variables/data?

Comment: Hello, you were right about the variables they weren't needed, I thought I had to declare them so $this->input->post would work in my model file. Also, I don't know about the fetch being synchronous, but I was able to find a solution to access the json from var response: simply returning response['response']. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the mime-type of your page so you can serve JSON data by using the [set_content_type()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html?highlight=json) method from the Output class.

Check the code

```
    public function process()
{
    $_POST = array_replace($_POST, json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true) ?? []);
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $status = $_POST["status"];
    $api = $_POST["key"];
    $duration = $_POST["duration"];
    if ($api == api_key){
        $result = $this->bot_model->add_log();
    }
    
    // JSON OUTPUT
    $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode( array("response" => $result)));
  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that when a function in CodeIgniter is called via post, the return of that function is whatever is printed out by the function in any way, be it echo, print_r, or var_dump. So to return your JSON file to App Script simply do `echo $json;`.